It possible to use Twilio's OTP (One-Time Password) generating service alongside dynamic content in my emails using Nodejs
const res = await client.verify
      .v2
      .services(twilioConfig.verifySid)
      .verifications.create({
        channelConfiguration: {
          template_id: templates.accountLinkingVerificationEmail, 
          from: process.env.SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL,
          dynamic_template_data: {
                    primary_name: primaryName,
                    secondary_name: secondaryName,
                },
        },
        to: childEmail,
        channel: 'email',
      })
      .then((verification) => console.log(verification.sid));

I'm trying to send dynamic content to populate my SendGrid dynamic templates. I receive the Twilio verification code in the {{twilio_code}} variable. However, when I try to use other dynamic values, such as {{primary_name}} and {{secondary_name}}, they aren't appearing in the email; they're showing up as empty strings. Can someone please help me resolve this? Thanks in advance.
